# What is the point of re-raising exceptions?

Tags: python, exception

So I've seen mention elsewhere of using the following to re-raise an exception.

```
try:
    whatever()
except:
    raise
```

What is the purpose re-raising an exception? Surely an uncaught exception will just raise to the top anyway? i.e:

```
try:
    int("bad")
except:
    raise
```

has identical output to:

```
int("bad")
```

i.e. I get a ValueError in the console.

Comment: It's useful when you do other stuff - for example printing out extra debugging information or cleaning up files

Comment: Generally you'd not *only* re-raise the exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine the following code.

A little setup: You are responsible for maintaining a huge database of information for example, and any loss of data would be catastrophic!

```
huge_dictionary = {'lots_of_important':['stuffs']}
try:
    check_data(new_data) #make sure the data is in the correct format
    huge_dictionary['lots_of_important'].append(new_data)
except:
    data_writer.backup(huge_dictionary)
    data_writer.close()
    #and any other last second changes
    raise
```

Answer (score 4):

Your example code is pointless, but if you wanted to perform logging or cleanup that only occurs on failure, you could put that between the `except:` and the `raise` and you'd do that work and then proceed as if the original exception was bubbling normally.

Comment: Ok, so if I'm happy to just take any exceptions raised by lower functions and just let something higher up in the application deal with them I can just not bother with try/except?

Comment: @DavidBoard: Yup. That a major advantage of exceptions over returning error codes; the functions that don't understand and can't do anything about a given exception don't need to write code to handle it at all, it just seamlessly bubbles up until it finds someone who can handle it.

Comment: this the real answer. `except: raise`(no other code) is pointless. But i do encounter it quite a bit, obscuring the real point of failure. Seems to be an effect of the exception-zen of python.

Comment: @semiomant: If it's actually a bare `raise`, it won't obscure the real point of failure (the original exception, including traceback, will resume bubbling up, as if it were never intercepted). But yes, on Python 2, if they raise a different exception without explicitly doing something to preserve information about the original exception, the original cause is lost (Python 3 chains exception contexts when a new exception is raised in an `except` or `finally` block, so the information isn't completely lost).