# Reraising exceptions in python idiomatically

Tags: python, exception, idioms

I was really curious if there is a difference between the two following blocks of code...

```
# block 1
def a_function():
    try:
        b_function()
    except Exception:
        raise

def b_function():
    raise Exception("Oh nooooo!")
```

and...

```
# block 2
def a_function():
        b_function()

def b_function():
    raise Exception("Oh noooooo!")
```

I know the first re-raises the `Exception` caught from the `b_function`, but is this really any different than the second block where I just let the `Exception` go up to either be caught later or stop the program? If they are the same effect, is one format more or less 'pythonic' than the other?

A similar question was asked at [What is the point of re-raising exceptions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39143878/what-is-the-point-of-re-raising-exceptions) but they don't mention how this effects the stacktrace. Does the first block change the 'source' of the error to `a_function` or does the `Exception` retain the source as being from `b_function`?

Comment: The way you're using them, there shouldn't be any functional difference, but in the first version, you could perform some additional clean-up or print additional debugging hints in the `except` clause before re-raising.
That being said, I'd probably use the second version unless I need the previously mentioned code path, or to make it obvious that I intend the specific exception to be propagated, and did not simply forget about it.
Not that I'm an expert for `pythonic`-ness, though.

Comment: @zondo: No-argument `raise` actually preserves the original traceback.

Comment: reraising without doing anything else is pointless - unless you plan to put a breakpoint there for debugging. You'll see it in examples where the intent is to have you do something about the exception.

Comment: Traceback is essentially the same (line numbers may be a little different). Try it and see.